# Remove Bootstrap Top Margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have the following in my Bootstrap layout,

```
<div class="row mt-4" id="content">
    <div class="col owl-carousel">
        <div class="slide text-center">
            <div class="innerslide">
                <h1>Registered In Total So Far</h1>
                    <p class="split-para align-middle">Total: <span id="total-registered"></span></p>
                    <p class="split-para align-middle">Durban: <span id="durban-registered"></span></p>
                    <p class="split-para align-middle">Pietermaritzburg: <span id="pmb-registered"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide text-center">
            <div class="innerslide">
                <h1>Registered In Last Hour</h1>
                <p class="split-para">Total: <span>409</span></p>
                <p class="split-para">Durban: <span>345</span></p>
                <p class="split-para">Pietermaritzburg: <span>74</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is set the mt-4 margin-top row to 0, once the screen is between a certain width. The problem I am having is when the page is viewed in landscape mode on certain size tablets or phones it is pushing the content to far down because I am using a fixed-bottom class for the footer row.

[image: Example of too much margin]
[image: Example of too much margin]

What I would like to do is remove that margin if the screen is in portrait mode and at that width. Using Responsinator, if I am understanding correctly. It is happening when the landscape width is between 667px and 736px.

This is basically what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Example of required view]

I have tried with the following code but it does not seem to make a difference:

```
@media (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #content {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and would be glad to give further information if required.

Thank you.

EDIT:  The solution just posting the correct code here in case it helps someone else. Thank you for the help!

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #content {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: try to use `!important`

Comment: Add orientation portrait to your media query

Comment: do it like this:`@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 768px) {
 #content{ margin-top: 0;}
 }`

Comment: Firstly, I must seriously apologize, I meant Landscape, not portrait. I did try the all the comment suggestions above and none made any difference.  I tried adding landscape orientation as well as !important and adjusted the media query as suggested, but still no luck.

Comment: It works!! Using orientation landscape and !important in the media query is what fixed it! Thank you guys so much for the help.